# How to set cookie on a browser using node js included API?

Tags: node.js, cookies, cross-domain

I am new to Node Js. I have made a node js based API which we can includes in any webpage to fetch its meta information. But I am unable to set cookie on browser for webpage using node js code. Means need to set cookie on non node js client from node js server.

For Example:

Suppose i have www.xyz.com website. and there is a node js api http://recc.xyz.com

Now i have include this api in www.xyz.com. Now i want to set cookie from recc.xyz.com to www.xyz.com. Is this is possible. yet not write the code. Please help me.

Comment: Set `Set-Cookie` response header

Comment: Show some code what you have tried.

Comment: For Example:

Suppose i have www.xyz.com website. and there is a node js api http://recc.xyz.com

Now i have include this api in www.xyz.com. Now i want to set cookie from recc.xyz.com to www.xyz.com. Is this is possible. yet not write the code. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a package like [cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies). It has a [method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies#cookiesset-name--value---options--) just for that